# Redirecting `stdin` on Linux? Or am I doing things wrongly?

Tags: python, linux, pipe, stdin

I got a simple run-until-terminated service.
At the end of it, once all threads are started, it has something like `input('Press something to terminate the program.')`. Now I want it to be called with few other services in a single chain like `python myservice.py && python myanotherservice.py`. Because of `input(...)` it waits for user to reply at the time `python service.py` is executed. Is there a way to redirect `stdin` to some special place that can never be read? Or what's the better way?

P.S. Yeah, I use Python, `input` method. Yet it shouldn't matter.

P.S.S. I don't care about termination remotely: service gonna die with entire VPS, so it's fine to be unable to terminate it once started.

Comment: Break down your question so its more readable.

Comment: It's called "daemon mode" - the program exits to shell but leaves a part of it running. Definitely should not be done with input from `stdin`, but I don't know how. I added this comment to clarify what's being asked.

Comment: I don't think you want the `input()` prompt at all. It sounds like you want a daemon program that runs in the background. See the linked question(s) for help making a daemon in Python.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, yeah, that service wasn't created with automation in mind.

Comment: Is this your Python script or a third party one you can't touch? If it's yours, use `python-daemon` to daemonize it. If you can't change it, you'll need to daemonize it from the outside. If it's the latter let me know and I'll change the duplicate question list.

Comment: I can change it once write access will be granted, thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a pipe :

```
echo | python myservice.py
```

This would supply an answer to the `input` and let the program continue.

Comment: Then it gonna be terminated immediately.